# Pushing a file to GitLab with Maven

Tags: maven, push, gitlab

I'm trying to push a file, the index.md from the markdown folder to my project stored in GitLab, I'm using Maven, but I don't know if it's possible to select just a single file to push it to GitLab.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to project folder and do that in your command in line terminal:

```
$ git add index.md
```

if it don't work do that :

```
$ git add -f index.md
```

where **`-f`** means **`forced`**

Then :

```
$ git commit -m index.md
$ git push
```